# In Bitbucket Pipeline, how to dynamically detect and start container with newly generated Docker image

Tags: docker, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

Here is my script after a new Docker image is built on the Docker Hub

```
docker ps // list my docker container so that I know its container ID
docker rm -f 1243432Ds32 //<- how do I dynamically know its id every time?
docker image ls // list the new image, so I can get the image id to remove
docker image rm dfs3423dx//<- how do I dynamically know its id every time?

docker pull myrepo/myprojet:init
docker image ls // list the new image, so I can get the image id to run
docker run -p -d 1280:80 9787dxe243 // <- how do I dynamically know its id every time?
```

As you can see that I need to run commands manually to get the current and new container/image IDs in order to remove or run them.

When writing a pipeline script, how can I replace the IDs with some dynamic variables to make the whole process automatic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

When running the image, use --name to specify the container name so that the pipeline script knows what container to remove
For the image name, it's just a format like: repository/name:tag

Problem solved :)

Comment: [`docker system prune`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/) will delete unused images, so in the sequence you show you can run that command after you `docker run` the new image to clean up the old one without manually looking up its ID.

Comment: thanks, yep I think I will add this line to clean all images, as I only need 1 image to run at any time.